# Rudin RCA ch. 1 ex. 12: Show that $\int_E|f|\,d\mu$ can be made arbitrarily small provided that $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\mu(E)$ is small

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Suppose $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Prove that to each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\int_E|f|\,d\mu<\epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$.

**PROOF** Let $\{M_n\}$ be a monotonically increasing real sequence which is not bounded above, and put $A_n=\{x:|f(x)|>M_n\}$, $A=\bigcap^\infty_{n=1} A_n$. Each $A_n$ is measurable and hence so is $A$. Since
$$\mu(A)M_n\leq\int_A|f|\,d\mu\leq\int_X|f|\,d\mu<\infty$$
for all $n$, $\mu(A)=\int_A|f|\,d\mu=0$. Also, $\mu(A_1)<\infty$, $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots$. Therefore
$$\int_{A_n}|f|\,d\mu\rightarrow\int_A|f|\,d\mu\text{.}$$
FIx $\epsilon>0$. Choose $n$ so that $\int_{A_n}|f|\,d\mu<\epsilon/2$, and choose $\delta>0$ so that $M_n\delta<\epsilon/2$. Then, for $E$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$,
$$\int_E|f|\,d\mu=\int_{E\setminus A_n}+\int_{E\cap A_n}\leq M_n\delta+\int_{A_n}|f|\,d\mu<\epsilon\text{,}$$
as was to be proved.

Any mistakes?

Comment: In this text $L^1(\mu)$ is the class of complex measurable function $f$ for which $\int_X|f|\,d\mu<\infty$.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not including a complex $\infty$ then.  In that case, I think your work could be simplified by noting $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: That's right. Thanks.

Comment: The only actual error I see is that you might have $\mu(A_1) = \infty$ based on what you've written. (though I'm not sure you need $\mu(A_1) < \infty$ -- I suppose it depends on what theorems you're using)

Comment: If $\mu(A_1)=\infty$ then we would have $\int_X|f|\,d\mu=\infty$, right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It's possible you wanted one more assumption on $M_1$ for that to be true, but there's no reason, for instance, $\mu(X) = \infty$ would imply $\int_X|f|\,d\mu = \infty$.

Comment: So I need to make $M_1>0$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An integral of a positive function over a "small" set is "small".](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679695/an-integral-of-a-positive-function-over-a-small-set-is-small)

Comment: @Oliver Diaz No. I ask for a solution-verification.